# Spring boot + security + angular2 served from embedded tomcat

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security, tomcat8, embedded-tomcat-8

I have rest service protected by spring security oauth2. Angular2 app is served from src/main/resources/static and it all works well. Basically all i need is  tomcat to fire up initial index.html page and then angular2 kicks in and does his job.

Up until this point everything is good. 
Now when client tries to access a protected resource with invalid credentials BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint will kick in and user will see blank page with one json message "401 blablalb".

Is there a more elegant way to handle this except creating dedicated login.html page and redirect to that page from extended BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint  ? Why i ask is if i do it this way i am not relying on angular2 guard system and redirection for unauthorized users this quickly becomes a nightmare if i want to redirect users to login page from angular2 app etc. Up until this point seems to me that for smaller projects serving both back and front-end from same server is a great way to ship product quickly.

Thanks

Comment: Your NG2 app should handle this. If you get a 401 back from the server, NG2 app should navigate to appropriate page (login or whatever).

Comment: if i get 401 im not even hitting ng2 app. When i navigate to say, localhost:8080/  
index.html from src/main/resources will be served and ng2 app will be bootstrapped,  but when i navigate to  localhost:8080/some-bad-path spring will look for some-bad-path.html or some-bad-path controller, when it does not find it spring will serve default 404.html page without any interaction with ng2 because ng2 will only do his magic if index.html is served.